# How to specify Input video device when I use ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use ffmpeg to record video in command line.

I tried:

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -f vfwcap -i 0 c:\test.mp4
```

And it pops up a window asking for "Video Source", Select a Video Device: "Integrated Camera". So I tried:

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -f vfwcap -i "Integrated Camera" c:\test.mp4
```

But it still pops up the same window. How I can specify the 'Integrated Camera' as my input device to ffmpeg?

Comment: You should show the output of: `ffmpeg -f vfwcap -i list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vfwcap is deprecated as mentioned [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam). You can use [dshow](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#dshow) instead of vfwcap.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Webcam" camera.mp4
```

Comment: Is there any way to mention the camera and audio index instead of name?  if possible please advise the ffmpeg args for the same.